# Equivalence relations and their classes

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

Check for which $k$ given relations on set $\mathbb{N}$ are reflexive, symmetric or  transitive. For these relations, that are equivalence relations, describe their equivalence classes.

> 1. $xR_ky \Longleftrightarrow k\:|\:(x+y)$
> 2. $xS_ky \Longleftrightarrow k\:|\:(x-y)$
> 3. $xT_ky \Longleftrightarrow x - y = k$

For the first example $xR_ky \Longleftrightarrow k\:|\:(x+y)$, I tried to do it like this:

- check if the relation $R_k$ is reflexive, so $xR_kx \Longleftrightarrow k\:|\:(x+x)\equiv k\:|\:2x$ - from that we get that $2x$ is always divisible if $k=1$ or $k=2$
- check if the relation $R_k$ is symmetric, so $\Big[xR_ky \Longleftrightarrow k\:|\:(x+y)\Big] \Longrightarrow \Big[yR_kx \Longleftrightarrow k\:|\:(y+x)\Big]$, which is true, because addition is commutative. From that we can conclude, that $\exists n\in\mathbb{N} : x+y=k\cdot n$.
- check if the relation $R_k$ is transitive, so $(xR_ky \wedge yR_kz) \Rightarrow xR_kz$.
  Thus $\exists n\in\mathbb{N} : x+y=k\cdot n$ and $\exists m\in\mathbb{N} : y+z=k\cdot m$.
  And this is the first moment that I got stuck and I am not sure what to do next. Though I suppose that it is going to be an equivalence relation, but what would its equivalence classes look like?

When it comes to examples (2) and (3) I can easily say that they are not equivalence relations, as in both cases $x-y \neq y-x$, which tells us that the relation is not symmetric.

Comment: Your argument for "symmetric" starts out well but then goes too far.  Yes, commutativity shows that $xR_ky\iff yR_kx$ but that certainly doesn't show that $k$ always divides $x+y$.

Comment: For transitive:  note that, for all $k$,  $1R_k(k-1) $ and $(k-1)R_k1$ but $1R_k1\iff k\in \{1,2\}$.  So unless $k$ is $1$ or $2$ transitivity fails.  Can you check $k=1,2$?

Comment: Final hint:  your argument for $(2)$ is much too hasty.  If $k$ divides $x-y$ then it also divides $y-x$.

Comment: I'm sorry for deleting my comment, but I accidentaly sent it before it was ready. Both $x$ and $y$ are $\mathbb{N}$, thus their sum is $\mathbb{N}$. And if $k = 1$, it divides any natural number.

Comment: Yes, if $k=1$.  Where did you say that you were only checking symmetry in the case $k=1$?

Comment: I did not say that, but it was my conclusion, as $x$ and $y$ can be any natural numbers and $1$ is divisor of all $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I don't understand.  The question is "for which $k$ is the relation $R_k$ symmetric?"  The first part of your argument shows that the answer is "for all $k$".     That's all you need to say.

Comment: Using your and Shubham's advices I got to the conclusion that relation (1) is equivalence relation for $k\in \{1,2\}$, but now I am struggling with its equivalence classes, as I have no idea how should I construct them. The only thing I had on the lecture was the definition, which is "Equivalence class of $a\in A$ in equivalence relation $R\subseteq A\times A$ is a set $[a]_R = \{b\in A\: |\: \langle a,b \rangle \in R\}$" - sadly it does not tell me much and I can not get it.

Comment: You just have to check the three properties...reflexive, symmetric, transitive.  That's it!

Comment: I did check these properties, as I wrote above - $R_k$ is equivalence relation for $k\in \{1,2\}$. But how should equivalence classes look according to my definiton?

Comment: I think you need to review your notes.  What you have defined there is an "equivalence class".  That means, given an equivalence relation, you break up the set into subsets such that every element in a subset is equivalent to every other but not equivalent to anything outside the subset.  For example, for $R_1$, everything is equivalent to everything so there is just one equivalence class.  For $R_2$ there are two (exercise:  identify those two classes).

Comment: So equivalence class for $R_2$ would probably be that $x,y$ are either both even or both odd, right?

Comment: Exactly correct,  Well, I'd phrase it as "the equivalence classes are the Even numbers and the Odd numbers".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.**

$(a)R_k$ is transitive for $k=1$, so we only need to check for $k=2$. If $x+y$ is even, either both $x,y$ are even or they are both odd. If $y$ is even, so is $z$ because $y+z$ is even. Similarly, if $y$ is odd, so is $z$. This means $x,z$ are either both even or both odd, or that $x\ R_2\ z$.

$(b)$ The equivalence of $S_k$ does not necessitate $x-y=y-x$. It only necessitates if $k|\ x-y$, then $k|\ y-x$, which is always true. In fact, $S_k$ is an equivalence relation $\forall k\in\Bbb N$.

$(c)$ Try $x-y=y-x=k=0$.

Comment: I proved that $R_k$ from example (a) is equivalence relation for $k\in \{1,2\}$ and in (b) that it is true $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$. When it comes to relation $xT_ky \Leftrightarrow x-y=k$ I know that it is reflexive for $k=0$ and symmetric for $k=0$, but I am not sure how to determine is transitive. According to earlier conclusion (that $k=0$), I think that it is enough to check if it works for $T_0$, which means $(x-y=0 \wedge y-z=0) \Rightarrow x-z=0$, the only case when it works is when $x=y=z$ - does it say that $T_0$ is not equivalence relation (because it works only in one case)?

Comment: $T_0$ is just the equality relation. It is transitive. By definition, if $T_0$ is transitive, then $x\ T_0\ y, y\ T_0\ z\implies x\ T_0\ z$. Now, $x\ T_0\ y\implies x=y; y\ T_0\ z\implies y=z\ \therefore x=z$ or $x\ T_0\ z$.

Comment: The fact that it only works in one case means the equivalence classes of $T_0$ are singleton. They are $\{1\},\{2\},\{3\}...$